# redis:- Get Modify Set value of key

Tags: redis

The following code gives errors:-

```
redisClient.get('aKey', function(err, aValue){
    //some operations.
    redisClient.set('aKey', aDashValue, function(err){
    if(err){ throw err };
        console.log('redisClient set sessionKey');
    });
});
```

I am trying to:- 1. Get key's value. 2. modify value 3. Set value. These 3 steps need to be done in immidiate succession.

Edit:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /Users/apple/Documents/herokuApp/node_modules/connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js:97:23
    at try_callback (/Users/apple/Documents/herokuApp/node_modules/redis/index.js:580:9)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (/Users/apple/Documents/herokuApp/node_modules/redis/index.js:670:13)
    at ReplyParser.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Documents/herokuApp/node_modules/redis/index.js:312:14)
    at ReplyParse
```

Comment: And the error is ...?

Comment: Put it in Edit. I couldn't follow what the error means. There is an concurrancy of command problem.

Comment: I think you got an exception in your code, which cannot be turned into something that can be handled by the "on error" handler. I would remove "if (err) { throw err };" and display err on the console instead.

Comment: @DidierSpezia you were right. There was an error beyond the code mentioned above. The update i was making had some errors. Sorry and Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token u` means you are trying to execute:

```
JSON.parse(undefined)
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

because "aValue" returns undefined in your case. Even if you did not specify it I deduced that your code was something like:

```
redisClient.get('aKey', function(err, aValue){
    if(err){ throw err };
    var aDashValue = JSON.parse(avalue);
    // change a value
    aDashValue.attr = true;
    redisClient.set('aKey', JSON.stringify(aDashValue), function(err){
    if(err){ throw err };
        console.log('redisClient set sessionKey');
    });
});
```

So a more generic approach would be:

```
/**
 * ChangeKeyValue
 * @param  {Object} redis redis client
 * @param  {String} key   key name
 * @param  {Function} fChanger(oldValue) -> {Object} change the attributes and returns an object
 * @param  {Function} f(err, replies) callback once done or on error)
 */
function changeKeyValue(redis, key, fChanger, f) {
  redis.watch(key, function(){

    redis.get(key, function(err, jsonStr) {
      var json;

      if (err) {
        return f(err)
      } else if(!jsonStr){
        return f(new Error("Key value is empty"));
      }

      try{
        json = JSON.parse(avalue);
      } catch(err){
        return f(err);
      }

      redis
        .multi()
        .set(key, JSON.stringify(fChanger(json)))
        .exec(f);
    });
  });
}

// Usage
changeKeyValue(redis, 'aKey', function(value){
  value.attr1 = "myNewValue";
  value.attr2++;
  return value;
}, function(err, replies){
  if(err){ throw err };
  console.log('redisClient set sessionKey');
});
```

However the best approach is still to use [**HASH**](http://redis.io/commands#hash) instead of [**STRING**](http://redis.io/commands#string) especially if you are using JSON.parse/stringify to increment attributes.